# I've created code in php which is below

Tags: php, syntax, syntax-error

```
//name length
            if(strlen($name)>100 || strlen($name)<3)
                exit("name must be <3 and >100");


            //message length
            if(strlen($message)>100 || strlen($message)<3)
                exit("message must be <3 and >100");

                $date = date("d-m-y");

            //Database
            $connection= mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','zatona');

            $querycheck=mysqli_query($connection,'INSERT INTO `message`(`name`, `message`, `date`) VALUES ('C:\\wamp\\www\\1\\{$name}', '$message', '$date')');

            if($querycheck == true)
            {
                //message
                echo "message added";
            }
            else{
                //error message
                echo "Error adding new message";
            }
                mysqli_close($connection);
        }
```

But It gives error  syntax error:

> unexpected '$name' (T_VARIABLE)

How can it be solved? using wamp server

Comment: A problem that wouldn't exist with mysqli parameter binding.

Answer (score 3):

You should either escape single quotes `'` in your query string or use double `"`:

```
 $querycheck = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO `message` (`name`, `message`, `date`) VALUES ('C:\\wamp\\www\\1\\$name', '$message', '$date')");
```

Comment: @KhaledR.Mahfuoz : On what line?

Comment: $querycheck = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO `message` (`name`, `message`, `date`) VALUES ('C:\\wamp\\www\\1\\{$name}', '$message', '$date')");

Comment: i think the problem in wamp or mysqli order

Comment: @KhaledR.Mahfuoz: It has nothing to do with this things – you surely have a typo somewhere.